# Adding JCEF Browser in jPanel within Netbeans Platform Application

Tags: java, chromium-embedded, netbeans-platform

I'm working on a Netbeans Platform application running on Java 11 in which I'd like to use the chromium browser from the JCEF project. (`org.jcef`)

I've already implemented the browser within an `org.openide.windows.TopComponent` and that works just fine by implementing it in the constructor like so:

```
public BrowserTopComponent() {
        initComponents();

        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.windowless_rendering_enabled = false;

        File jcef_helper = InstalledFileLocator.getDefault().locate(
                "modules/lib/jcef_helper.exe",
                "com.mycompany.nbm.browser",
                false);
        settings.browser_subprocess_path = jcef_helper.getAbsolutePath();
        modules_path = jcef_helper.getAbsolutePath().split("modules")[0] + "modules";

        cefApp_ = CefApp.getInstance(settings);

        client_ = cefApp_.createClient();

        browser_ = client_.createBrowser(HOME, false, false);
        browerUI_ = browser_.getUIComponent();

        add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }
```

Now I'd like to include the browser in another `TopComponent` but not in its entire area, but instead within just one `jPanel`.

Theoretically that should be possible by exchanging `add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);` from the previous code with:

```
jPanelBrowser.add(browerUI_, BorderLayout.CENTER);
jPanelBrowser.validate();
```

That however did not work at all. It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't do anything.

If anyone has any experience in making jcef work in such a scenario, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am also facing this problem, have you found the solution?

Comment: Sadly no, not yet. I didn't have much more time to look for it though.  If I ever find a solution, I will post it here.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue and found that when you are adding it to a `JPanel` you have to set the size of the client.

```java
client_.setSize(800, 600)
```

Once I did that it showed for me.